# MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `model.pojo class` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)

Tags: java, jackson, json-deserialization, rest-assured

I have created couple of POJO classes for serializing/deserializing. When I create a request to receive all categories I am expecting to receive an array of category objects. But I am getting the following error:-

> Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type POJO.Categories from Array value (token JsonToken.START_ARRAY)

**1. This is my test class and I try to map the response to my POJO class(model) but it gives me an error.**

```
@Test(alwaysRun = true, priority = 1)
public void getUserDetail() {
        String url = "http://localhost:8081/users";
        RequestSpecification httpRequest = RestAssured.given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .contentType(ContentType.JSON);

        Response response = httpRequest.get(url);
        ResponseBody responseBody = response.getBody();
        UsersResponseDetails b = responseBody.as(UsersResponseDetails.class);
        softAssert.assertEquals(b.getId(), 1,"invalid");
        softAssert.assertAll();
    }
```

**2. Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `model.UsersResponseDetails` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`)
 at [Source: (String)"[{"id":1,"name":"litteleHelpByKR-1","dob":"2020-05-23T","addressDetails":{"houseNumber":"H-55","aadharNumber":32345,"addressLine1":"Mg Road-1","addressLine2":"12th Cross-1","landmark":"Near Airport Road","pin":1,"officeAddress":{"buildingNumber":3,"addressLine1":"XYZ-1","addressLine2":"Airport Road","landMark":"Near U turn signal","cardId":"EMP-001","pin":75943764}}}]"; line: 1, column: 1]
```

**3. Used Jackson dependent but its not work**

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.13.4</version>
 </dependency>
```

**4. API GET response**

```
[
   {
      "id":1,
      "name":"litteleHelpByKR-1",
      "dob":"2020-05-23T",
      "addressDetails":{
         "houseNumber":"H-55",
         "aadharNumber":32345,
         "addressLine1":"Mg Road-1",
         "addressLine2":"12th Cross-1",
         "landmark":"Near Airport Road",
         "pin":1,
         "officeAddress":{
            "buildingNumber":3,
            "addressLine1":"XYZ-1",
            "addressLine2":"Airport Road",
            "landMark":"Near U turn signal",
            "cardId":"EMP-001",
            "pin":75943764
         }
      }
   }
]
```

**5. This model I created to map the response**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class UsersResponseDetails {
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private String dob;
    private AddressDetails addressDetails;

    @Getter
    @Setter
    public static class AddressDetails {
        private String houseNumber;
        private int aadharNumber;
        private String addressLine1;
        private String addressLine2;
        private String landmark;
        private int pin;
        private OfficeAddress officeAddress;

        @Getter
        @Setter
        public static class OfficeAddress {
            private int buildingNumber;
            private String addressLine1;
            private String addressLine2;
            private String landMark;
            private String cardId;
            private int pin;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your endpoint returns an array.

Comment: As tgdavies already stated yur json contains a 1-element array: `[...]` means an array and you have `[{...}]`. So you need to parse the json into a list or array of `UsersResponseDetails` details.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My suggesstion are:

- If you want to work with array, then

```
UsersResponseDetails[] b = responseBody.as(UsersResponseDetails[].class);
softAssert.assertEquals(b[0].getId(), 1,"invalid");
```

- If you prefer List, then

```
List<UsersResponseDetails> b= responseBody.as(new TypeRef<List<UsersResponseDetails>>() {});
softAssert.assertEquals(b.get(0).getId(), 1,"invalid");
```